# Lerna + TypeScript - Solving import declaration conflicts with local declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, redux-saga, lerna

I have just installed TypeScript in one of my packages / sub-projects of a lerna monorepo. No other projects use TypeScript, so I didn't feel the need to install typescript on the Lerna base.

Everything went fine unless for the fact that I got `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of ...` with types of two libraries.

The libraries were `redux-saga` and `react-pose / pose-popmotion`.
I have tried many things, like using noHoist setting in the base packages.json... nothing worked.
So I ended up setting `skipLibCheck: true` on tsconfig and now I can build my project again.

I wonder if this will make typescript less reliable?

Is there a big disadvantage of using `skipLibCheck`?

And would there be a cleaner solution for solving `Import declaration conflicts` issues?

Thanks a lot for your inputs!